# incorporating AnimatedMarker plugin with react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have chosen this plugin because it seems like the best way to animate a marker on a map polyline.

It's not on npm so I just added `module.exports = L.animatedMarker` to AnimatedMarker.js from the repository and required it.

App.js

```
<AnimatedMarkerElement 
  route={this.state.route} 
  map={this.refs.map.leafletElement}
/>
```

AnimatedMarkerElement.js

```
require('./AnimatedMarker')
import { MapComponent } from 'react-leaflet'
import L from 'leaflet'

export default class AnimatedMarkerElement extends MapComponent {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const line = L.polyline([nextProps.route.coordinates]),
      animatedMarker = L.animatedMarker(line.getLatLngs())

    nextProps.map.addLayer(animatedMarker)
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null
```

I think that the plugin is looking for a map that it can't find because its buried inside react elements.

Comment: Check if  line.getLatLngs() returns anything

Comment: That returns an array of latlng objects.

Comment: Is the plugin compatible with your Leaflet version 0.7 or 1.0 ?

Comment: Also why are you using nextProps.map ? You should not get map in your next props , try to use this.refs.map

Comment: this.refs.map.leafletElement right?  I pass that as a property to AnimatedMarkerElement.

Comment: yeah , like this.refs.map.leafletElement.addLayer(animatedMarker)

Comment: but the map element isn't in AnimatedMarkerElement.js, so it can't see that ref.

Answer (score 0):

```
const line = L.polyline([nextProps.route.coordinates]),
```

should actually be

```
const line = L.polyline(nextProps.route.coordinates),
```

I was nesting an array inside an array.